# Login using client SSL certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, ssl-certificate

I want users to be able to login to say, Jenkins using client SSL certificates without password.

Let me rephrase it:  The certificate part works fine. I want to find a way for apache to tell web aplication, such as Jenkins, that user X is already authenticated so that he/she does not need to provide login/password pair in the web application.

I've setup apache to only let through clients with valid certificates. But still they have to login using passwords.

Any pointers?
Unfortunately search engines are flooded with Q/A about regular server-side certs and password login.

My configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/public_html/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/ssl/server.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/ssl/server.key

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SSLCACertificateFile /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/ssl/ca.cer
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where's your configuration?

Comment: password is likely on client certificate, thud s you have to enter password when adding certificate to browser. If you can issue password less certificate, no password would be required.

Comment: @Archemar: Let me rephrase: The certificate part works fine. I'm want to find a way for apache to tell webaplication, such as Jenkins, that user X is already authenticated so that he/she does not need to provide login/password pair in the webapplication.

Comment: This is a matter of the application! You do need to tell apache anything! You need to change the application (e.g. Jenkins) to look for the SSL_CLIENT_DN in the server variables. Then you need to map the DN to your username. Either your application already has a module that supports client certificates or you need to write such a module yourself. Grab the DN, split it, so that you only use the CN or the email and pass this as username to the application.